# Deadlock in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

When performing transaction with large number of devices, deadlock error is occurring. I am using MySQL. Huge number of devices will access the database at the same time. This causes Error Code 1205.

Any suggestion...??

Comment: Dude, if you have concurrency ... then you have the risk of deadlocks!  How do you mitigate the risk?  That's a BIIIIIIIIG topic - there's no simple answer.  SUGGESTION: analyze your application's behavior, and try to identify where most of the deadlocks are occurring.  Learn "explain plan".  Check your indexes.  Know your queries.

Comment: -1 we do not have a magic ball, post your code if you expect any kind of help...

Answer (score 1):

from [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_lock_wait_timeout):

> Message: Lock wait timeout exceeded; **try restarting transaction**

this says it all. another qiestion is how to find out what's causing the timeout - but thats almost impossible to tell with the given information. you'll have to provide some numbers (how much is "a huge number"; how much (and wich) statements are executed in your transaction) and some information about your table-structures that are involved.

if there's no way to speed up your transaction any more, you could edit your `my.cnf` and increase the timeout (`innodb_lock_wait_timeout`) or, if you jst want to increase the timeout for this transaction, call `SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120;` before starting it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few places you can start:

- http://www.serveradminblog.com/2011/03/tuning-mysql-performance-howto-part-1/
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html

Your question is hopelessly broad.  You need to do some homework, and get some facts.  It's hard work - but it's absolutely necessary.

IMHO...